# Can you create a dedupe rule to include individual and organisation details

Tags: duplicate-contacts

Following recent Events/bookings we have found several duplicate organisations have been created.  We used the Name and Email (reserved) Supervised dedup rule and while duplicate individuals have not been created we now have many duplicated organisations.

Any assistance with this issue would be most appreciated as we are due to launch another event which will probably have well over 100 bookings.

Thank you
Allison

Hi Allison

Does the settings for the Organisation Name field look like this?
[image: profile screenshot]

Comment: You can use the same functionality for deduping for organisations as for individuals. The only thing which differs are the rules you use. If you go to Contact --> Duplicate Contacts you can use a rule for organisations such as Name and E-mail address.

Comment: Hi Jaap Jansma - thank you for responding so quickly.  I think you may have misunderstood my question.  I am trying to find out if you can create a combined dedupe rule where if you use the Individuals rule you can add in a field for Organisation also - we are running events and while we have solved the issue of duplicate contacts being created, we have found that now duplicate organisations are being created.  Do you have any ideas?  I look forward to any response you can give to assist us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is no. Dedupes for individuals and oranisations are handled separately in Civi.

I'm assuming (and feel free to correct me if I'm wrong) you've got an event booking profile for an individual which includes the current employer field.

From Manage events list. Find the event in question.
From the configure options at the RH side of the screen select configure, then online registration.

Under the heading Registration Screen you'll find links to the profiles used to gather contact details. Check the Organisation Name field to see how it is configured. Frequently this uses the current employer field from the contact record.

Soenthing like this[image: profile screenshot]

Civi will apply the specified dedupe rule to the new individual details and match as required.

There won't be a dedupe rule specified for the organisation so Civi will apply the Organisation- Unsupervised Rule (Default setting for any situation where members of the public are adding contact details)

From Contacts> Find and Merge Duplicate Contacts
Scroll down to the Organisation, Unsupervised rule. Edit the rule to check how it is configured.

If your organisation- unsupervised rule is anymore complicated than match by organisation name only. Civi will decide there is not enough info to match, and then create a duplicate organisation.

If you have permissions you can edit the rule to match on the Organisation Name only field

If your matching rule is name only, you may still get duplicate organisations in a "Judean People's Front/ People's Front of Judea" scenario. As different users may record their organisation name in a non standard fashion.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Craig, thank you for responding so quickly - at present our event booking profile does not include the current employer field.  It may be that this would resolve our issue.  When my colleague returns after the weekend we will look into this.  Thank you again for your expertise.

Comment: Hi Allison,

Can you give details on how you're capturing the contacts at the moment, please?

Are your contacts signing up themselves from a civi registration page?

How exactly are you gathering the organisation detail along with the individual detail?

Comment: Hi Craig, our events are set up for contacts to register themselves.  The event profile contains a field asking for their organisation name - we use this for monitoring purposes.  Do you think this field may be causing the problem?  Please excuse my lack of knowledge but I have only been using CiviCRM for a very short time.  Any help would be most appreciated - I have screen shots of our set up if you think they may be helpful.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi Allison,

I've added a screenshot to your question of the way we set up a registration profile. Does this match the way your Organisation Name field is configured.

Comment: Hi Craig, apologies for the delay in getting back to you, it has been a bit on the busy side here the last few days.  Being quite new to Civi Events could you please point me in the right direction to see where the settings fields are located, have looked around our system but seem to be going in circles.  Thank you and I look forward to hearing from you

Comment: Hi Allison,

I've fleshed out my answer with the places you need to look
Event profile
Duplicate Matching rules

Comment: Hi Craig - checked our Organisation/Unsupervised rule and only field selected was Email - I have changed this to Organisation Name and will monitor what happens.  We are currently running events where people are registering so hopefully we will see if any duplicates are created over the next couple of days.  I will let you know how we get on and thank you so much for all your help.  Allison

Comment: Hi Craig, sorry for the delay in getting back to you - we have had only a few more bookings on our events but no duplicates have been created.  Looks like your very helpful advice has cracked our problem.  Thank you again for all the help and assistance you have given us.

Comment: No worries Allison. Glad I was able to help.

If you can take a moment to "accept" my answer it will take this question out of the unanswered queue. Cheers

Comment: Hi Craig, apologies for lateness in getting back to you - I have now 'accepted' your answer and again, many thanks for your assistance with our issue which now seems to be resolved.

Comment: Again. Not a problem. And hanks for accepting the answer